# Identifying orientation not responding

Tags: ios, interface, orientation

I am having a problem calling a void when my view loads to identify the orientation of my iDevice. It only gets called when my view rotates then it does get called, but I want it to get called from the very beginning of my program. Here's what I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    free(machine);

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = app.statusBarOrientation;
    [self doLayoutForOrientation:currentOrientation];
}
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    [self doLayoutForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void)doLayoutForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        [self layoutPortrait];
    } else {
        [self layoutLandscape];
    }
}

- (void)layoutPortrait {

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"]) {

        self.autonomousOnPlayingField.frame = CGRectMake(218, 40, 94, 28);
        self.redAutonomousOnPlayingField.frame = CGRectMake(218, 40, 94, 28);

        self.autonomousReleasedKickstand.frame = CGRectMake(218, 77, 94, 28);
        self.redAutonomousReleasedKickstand.frame = CGRectMake(218, 77, 94, 28);

        self.autonomousParkingZoneStepper.frame = CGRectMake(218, 37, 94, 29);
        self.redAutonomousParkingZoneStepper.frame = CGRectMake(218, 37, 94, 29);

        self.autonomousWithAutonomousBallStepper.frame = CGRectMake(218, 74, 94, 29);
        self.redAutonomousWithAutonomousBallStepper.frame = CGRectMake(218, 74, 94, 29);

        self.autonomousCenterGoal.frame = CGRectMake(218, 33, 94, 28);
        self.redAutonomousCenterGoal.frame = CGRectMake(218, 33, 94, 28);

    } else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"]) {




    } else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"]) {



    } else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"i386"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"]) {


    }
}

- (void)layoutLandscape {

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"]) {

        self.autonomousOnPlayingField.frame = CGRectMake(213, 40, 347, 28);
        self.redAutonomousOnPlayingField.frame = CGRectMake(213, 40, 347, 28);

        self.autonomousReleasedKickstand.frame = CGRectMake(213, 77, 347, 28);
        self.redAutonomousReleasedKickstand.frame = CGRectMake(213, 77, 347, 28);

        self.autonomousParkingZoneStepper.frame = CGRectMake(466, 37, 94, 29);
        self.redAutonomousParkingZoneStepper.frame = CGRectMake(466, 37, 94, 29);

        self.autonomousWithAutonomousBallStepper.frame = CGRectMake(466, 74, 94, 29);
        self.redAutonomousWithAutonomousBallStepper.frame = CGRectMake(466, 74, 94, 29);

        self.autonomousCenterGoal.frame = CGRectMake(213, 33, 347, 28);
        self.redAutonomousCenterGoal.frame = CGRectMake(213, 33, 347, 28);

    } else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"]) {



    } else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"]) {




    } else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"i386"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"]) {


    }
}
```

What can I do so that I can call `(void)doLayoutForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation` from my `(void)viewDidLoad`?